# How to compute $\mathbb{E}(\prod_{i=1}^n(1+X_i)\textbf{1}_{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+X_i)\leq M})$

Tags: probability

I want to compute $\mathbb{E}(\prod_{i=1}^n(1+X_i)\textbf{1}_{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+X_i)\leq M})$, where $\textbf{1}$ is the indicator function and $X_i$ are continuous  independent and equidistributed random variables with density function $f_{X_i}$. I have tried the next:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1, \ldots, X_n} (x_1, \ldots, x_n)\textbf{1}_{(1+x_1) \cdots (1+x_n) \leq M }dx_1 \ldots dx_n$$

and as $X_i$ are independent:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdots  f_{X_n}(x_n)\ (1+x_n)\textbf{1}_{(1+x_1)) \cdots (1+x_n) \leq M })dz_1 \ldots dz_n$$

However, I do not know  how to continue (if it is possible).

Comment: Indicator is a function of the form $1(x\in A)$, but it seems you only have $1(x)$ which is missing some important information.

Comment: @Ilya It is edited, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the shape of the indicator function does not allow you using the independence in the full power. Yet, some simplifications can  be made.

1. Your integral is of the form 
   $$
     E = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x\,1(x\leq M) \;\mathrm d F_n(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^M x \;\mathrm d F_n(x) = M\cdot F_n(M) - \int\limits_{-\infty}^M F_n(x) \;\mathrm d x
   $$
   where $F_n$ is the CDF of $\xi_n = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+X_i)$.
2. Assuming that $X_i > -1$ and denoting $Y_i = 1+X_i > 0$ you obtain an iterative construction for $F_n$ starting with $F_1$ being the CDF of $Y$:
   $$
     F_n(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty F_{n-1}(x/y)\;\mathrm dF_1(y).
   $$

Comment: So, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_1}(x_1)\cdots  f_{X_n}(x_n)\ (1+x_n)\textbf{1}_{(1+x_1)) \cdots (1+x_n) \leq M })dz_1 \ldots dz_n$$ is equal to $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x\,1(x\leq M) \;\mathrm f_n(x)$ where $f_n$ is the  density function of $\xi_n = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+X_i)?$

Comment: Is case of beeing this way, how do you reach this density?